# Nginx reverse proxy for grafana using dashboard as subpath

Tags: nginx, grafana, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to use `dashboard` as my nginx location for my grafana install.

The problems is grafana uses dashboard in some of it url's like `https://example.com/grafana/dashboard/new?orgId=1`, where I would like it to be `https://example.com/dashboard/dashboard/new?orgId=1` and I think my nginx location is rewriting to `https://example.com/dashboard/new?orgId=1`.

When I have it setup to use `grafana` as the subpath it all work as expected;

grafana.ini:

```
[server]
http_addr = 127.0.0.1
domain = example.com
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/grafana/
```

nginx config:

```
# Upstream Servers
upstream grafana_server {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /grafana/ {
        proxy_pass http://grafana_server/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

But changing it to `dashboard` and navigating to `https://example.com/dashboard/dashboard/new?orgId=1` results in the url been rewritten to `https://example.com/dashboard/new?orgId=1`

grafana.ini:

```
[server]
http_addr = 127.0.0.1
domain = example.com
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/dashboard/
```

nginx config:

```
# Upstream Servers
upstream grafana_server {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /dashboard/ {
        proxy_pass http://grafana_server/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

so I have tried a to do a rewrite in the nginx location but can't get it to work as required (really have no clue what to do here)

```
location ~ (\/dashboard\/) {
    proxy_pass http://grafana_server$1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location ~ /dashboard/ {
    rewrite ^ /dashboard/$1;
    proxy_pass http://grafana_server;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late - but I stumbled upon the same issue and thought I'd going to share in case somebody else hits this thread:

This isn't an issue with nginx, but with grafana itself.

I could not solve it any other way but renaming the last part of the `root_url` in something different than `/dashboard`

Comment: Thanks Phil, I found the same and ended up using `/dashboards` and all seems to be working.